# Pass parameter value of one controller to another in mvc .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

i **want to pass parameter value of first(layername) controller to second controller. without redirect** to second controller.. thanks. for any help..

first controller:-

```
Public ActionResult firstcontroller(DataTable dt, String layertype, String layername)

{
query= "some sql query" + layertype+ "where=" +layername+ ;

}
```

Second Controller:-

```
Public ActionResult secondcontroller(DataTable dt, String searchval, String selectval)

{
query= "some sql query" + searchval+ "where=" +layername+ ;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _without redirect_? (and you should remove the pointless `DataTable dt` parameter in both methods)

Comment: Passing parameter from a controller to another one called "redirect". In what purpose you have `DataTable` as argument? You should pass viewmodel class instead of a `DataTable` collection from view. Side note: Don't use string concatenation to build a DB query, use parameterized version instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you need but if you want without redirection then using the session in the following way should work for you:

```
Public ActionResult firstcontroller(DataTable dt, String layertype, String layername)
{
 Session["layername"]=layername;
 query= "some sql query" + layertype+ "where=" +layername+ ;
}


Public ActionResult secondcontroller(DataTable dt, String searchval, String selectval)
{
 var layername = Session["layername"].toString();
 query= "some sql query" + searchval+ "where=" +layername+ ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `session` is not advisable.Use `TempData` instead

```
Public ActionResult firstcontroller(DataTable dt, String layertype, String 
layername)
{
TempData["layername"]=layername;
query= "some sql query" + layertype+ "where=" +layername+ ;
}


Public ActionResult secondcontroller(DataTable dt, String searchval, String 
selectval)
{
var layername = TempData["layername"].toString();
query= "some sql query" + searchval+ "where=" +layername+ ;
}
```